# How to a setup virtual router on windows so that one can access internet from a mobile using static ip

Tags: wireless-networking, android, static-ip, windows-networking

Some Relevant information

- My Os is Windows 8
- I am accessing internet via a dongle
- I also share the internet using virtual router(so that i can access internet in my phone)
- My phone got into trouble and i can't connect to router when IP settings is DHCP(in my phone)
- So i tried static IP and now i can connect to router but i can't access internet

Is there any way i can connect to internet from my phone using that static settings?
If so what modification should i make in network properties in my system and phone(Android)?

Comment: Without DHCP, you will have to set the default gateway and DNS server manually to your computer on your phone.

Comment: @user3767013 Which gateway and dns must i select(Dongle or Virtual adapter)? My dongle has got   a dns server and gateway address. But the virtual adapter default gateway is empty.

Comment: Try virtual Adapter at first.